# MYSQL: Right join not returning expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to grab data from three different tables, and I am trying to display all the rows in the other tables by using the RIGHT JOIN however I don't seem to be returning them...

```
SELECT id, user_name, first_name, last_name FROM vtigercrm600.vtiger_users
RIGHT JOIN vtigercrm600.vtiger_users2group
    on vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.id = vtigercrm600.vtiger_users2group.userid
RIGHT JOIN vtigercrm600.vtiger_groups
    on vtigercrm600.vtiger_users2group.groupid = vtigercrm600.vtiger_groups.groupid
WHERE vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.id = '5'
group by vtiger_users.id;
```

I am getting the following from this

```
||ID||user_name||first_name||last_name||
|| 5||user1    ||john      ||smith    ||
```

But I was expecting data from the other tables such as

```
||ID||user_name||first_name||last_name||groupid||userid||groupname ||description     ||
|| 5||user1    ||john      ||smith    ||     14||     5||Sales Dept||Sales Dept Group||
```

users table

```
||id||user_name||first_name||last_name||
```

users2group table

```
||groupid||userid||
```

groups table

```
||groupid||groupname||description||
```

Comment: Switch to `LEFT JOIN` (incl swapping tables.) Most people find left join hard enough, and RIGHT JOIN is just too confusing. When that's done, I'll take another look at it.

Comment: Why would you expect data to be returned when it's not included in the SELECT !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry because I assumed just doing a join would include everything automatically... I clearly assumed wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `right join`, then the `where` clause should only contain conditions on the *last* table.  However, I don't recommend using `right join`s.  Most people find `left join` much easier to follow -- because it keeps all rows in the first table.

I think you should try using `left join` instead . . . with the tables in the same order.  To get columns from other tables, you need to include the *columns* in the `select`.

I suspect it is the logic you want:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_name, u.first_name, u.last_name, g.*
FROM vtigercrm600.vtiger_users u LEFT JOIN
    vtigercrm600.vtiger_users2group ug
    on u.id = ug.userid LEFT JOIN
    vtigercrm600.vtiger_groups g
    on ug.groupid = g.groupid
WHERE u.id = 5;
```

Notes:

- Your query doesn't seem to need a `group by`.  I don't see any aggregation.
- If `id` is a number, then don't use single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The `LEFT JOIN` can probably be replaced by `INNER JOIN` -- although you will get no rows if the user is in no groups.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should get in the habit of qualifying all column names.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You need to list all columns you need from all tables in SELECT statement. Like

```
SELECT vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.id, vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.user_name, vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.first_name, vtigercrm600.vtiger_users.last_name, vtigercrm600.vtiger_groups.groupname, vtigercrm600.vtiger_groups.description ...
```